# Throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am doing one application in android for that I need to access com.android.internal.telephony APIs. Now I am able to access those APIs but problem is wherever I call the `getEarliestConnection()` method of Class Call.java in my own class it's throwing a `NullPointerException`.
You can find Call.java here http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java.html. In this class there is the following method:

```
1.    public Connection
2.        getEarliestConnection() {
3.            List l;
4.            long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
5.            Connection c;
6.            Connection earliest = null;
7.    
8.            l = getConnections();
9.  
10.            if (l.size() == 0) {
11.                return null;
12.            }

        for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
            c = (Connection) l.get(i);
            long t;

            t = c.getCreateTime();

            if (t < time) {
                earliest = c;
                time = t;
            }
        }

        return earliest;
    }
```

I want to call this method in my class. the class Call.java ia an abstract class I created subclass of Call class and called the above method like this:

```
Call myCall = new MyCall();
Connection myConn = new MyConn();
myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
```

But It's throwing a `NullPointerException` on line no:10 of above method and line no:3 of above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `getConnections()` returns null here and you cannot get the size of the null-object.

Here's how to fix it:

```
if (l == null || l.size() == 0) 
{
    return null;
}
```

So, if for some unknown reason, there is no Connection-List or the list is empty, `null` will be returned. Using the operator `||` will do the same as

```
if (l == null)
{
    return null;
}
else if ( l.size() == 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thk you very much, I'll try it

Answer (score 4):

Presumably `getConnections()` is returning null, so `l` is null, so trying to call `l.size()` is throwing the exception. We don't know what `getConnections()` does though.

Note that this looks suspicious too:

```
Connection myConn = new MyConn();
myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
```

Why are you creating an instance of `MyConn` in the first line, only to throw it away again? Why not just use:

```
Connection myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
```

In general, it's worth declaring local variables as late as you can, ideally when you have a useful value - so in your method, you could declare `c` *within* the loop, assign `t` a value in the declaration, declare `l` at the point of assignment, etc. You should also consider using generics where possible - e.g. `List<MyConn>` instead of just the raw `List` type.

EDIT: In contrast to the accepted answer, I would suggest changing `getConnections()` to *always* return a non-null value, returning an empty list if there are no connections. That will be easier to work with.

Comment: Bcoz Connection class is an abstract class so that I created sub class of Connection class.

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of MyConn in the first line, only to throw it away again? for this I commented

Comment: @shiv1229: But your comment doesn't actually explain why you're doing this. Why assign a value to a variable, and then immediately assign a new value to the variable? Just because you've got an abstract class doesn't explain that line of code at all. If the constructor has some side-effect, you could just call that *without* assigning the value to a variable - and add a comment to say why you're doing it.

Comment: @shiv1229: See my edit for an alternative fix to the NullPointerException. Generally speaking, a method which returns a collection is better off returning an empty collection than a null reference - if you change your `getConnections()` method, you don't need to change your `getEarliestConnection()` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6429/discussion-between-shiv1229-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 2):

Your cm variable has been never initialized before getConnections() call. So, it is null and you get NullPointerException when trying to invoke cm.getActiveFgCall().

Comment: @Artm: Thx for ur reply .I tried to intialized it but I can't. How to intialize this. plz help me.

Comment: CallManager is an internal class, how were you planning on getting to it?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: what is OP. I am not getting

Comment: OP stands for `original poster`, so that is you! Your line number 10 was two lines below the error.

Answer (score 0):

You method

```
l = getConnections();
```

returns `null`, so your line 10 should look like: `if (l==null) {`

Answer (score 0):

The method `getEarliestConnection()` makes a call to `getConnections()` which returns `null`.

Since `getConnections()` is abstract in `Call` check the method you've provided in `MyCall`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot

```
CallManager cm;    
cm = new CallManager();
```

Comment: Thx deepak, I tried it but its showing an error like this: 'The constructor CallManager() is not visible'. I think it is bcoz of CallManger.java is an filal modifier.

Comment: No. This is because CallManager's constructor is not public.
Final modifier means that class cannot be inverited.

Comment: CallManager is a class for internal use. Even if you could instantiate it(e.g. using reflection) there is no guarantee that it will work properly.