# Getting NullpointerExcepiton

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Throwing null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741215/throwing-null-pointer-exception)

I am using `com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager` class. It is a final modifier class. You can find this class here http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java.html.

I need to use the following method from CallManger.java and called like this:

```
Call fgCall = cm.getActiveFgCall();
```

Here Call is an abstract class you can find here http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java.html.

I created a subclass of this class like this :

```
public class MyCall extends Call{   
        Call myCall;
        CallManager cm;
     private final ArrayList<Connection> emptyConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();


@Override
public List<Connection> getConnections() {
    Call fgCall = cm.getActiveFgCall();
    System.out.println("**inside getConnections"+fgCall);
  if ( fgCall != null) {

            return fgCall.getConnections();
        }
        return emptyConnections;

    }

    @Override
    public Phone getPhone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void hangup() throws CallStateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMultiparty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public Connection
    getEarliestConnection() {
        List l;
        long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        Connection c;
        Connection earliest = null;

        l = getConnections();

        if (l == null) {
            return null;
        }else if ( l.size() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
            c = (Connection) l.get(i);
            long t;

            t = c.getCreateTime();

            if (t < time) {
                earliest = c;
                time = t;
            }
        }

        return earliest;
    }

}
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException` on line No:8, Actually I want a non-null value from getConnetion method. What I have to do to get a value from `getConnetion();`
Thx in advance

Comment: May be double thread (similar) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745765/getting-null-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741215/throwing-null-pointer-exception